# Wordpress rest api returning an empty JSON result

Tags: php, json, rest, wordpress

On my wordpress site the Wordpress Rest API plugin used to work correctly and return all posts when I went to:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

but now it returns an empty json `[]`

I know this is very little info to go on but what are the usual suspects when troubleshooting such an issue?

Some history on how we got into this mess: The staging environment was copied to live just before the issue occurred.
- Some changes were made to theme.php and function.php. Those changes have since been removed in trying to figure out why the endpoint is returning an empty json
- I have created new posts and they don't show up
- There is no error on console.log

Comment: I think you have to debug the plugin that generates the rest-api and returns the json. So you know when the mysql result is thrown away or altered and which method is the problem.